# Combine key value functions with NSExpression

Tags: ios, core-data, collections, key-value-coding

Can I combine key value collection functions with `NSExpression`? I was using it with CoreData to get the max: of a value from my managed object classes, and it was working great.

Now i have this other managed object class which contains an `NSSet`. I want to find the max: of the @sum of values in the `NSSet`.

So for example, I have 10 managed objects, each with an NSSet of values. I want to @sum the values in each set, and then find the largest one of the 10 managed objects.

I would usually get the sum using `[object valueForKeyPath:@"usageMetrics.@sum.value"]` - which works fine.

I want to combine and do somethinge like:

```
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"usageMetrics.@sum.value"];
NSExpression *valueSumExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"max:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
```

It doesn't seem to be working

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid keypath element (not a relationship or attribute): @sum'
```

Comment: The sum of a collection is a single value, not a collection. `max` only makes sense for a collection. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yup, my post wasn't quite clear: I added this: "So for example, I have 10 managed objects, each with an NSSet of values. I want to @sum the values in each set, and then find the largest one of the 10 managed objects."

Comment: Also, the error is actually: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid keypath element (not a relationship or attribute): @sum'. So I then tried to add a method to my managed object which encapsulates this call: - (NSNumber *) weekTotal {
    return [self valueForKeyPath:@"usageMetrics.@sum.value"];
}
...and it complains that weekTotal isn't found on the managed object either (probably because it's transient).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this:

```
NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"usageMetrics.value"]; 
NSExpression *valueSumExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:" arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
```

which returns an NSArray of 12 results (this is how many managed objects it found) and it has summed the values.

I then do:

```
NSDecimalNumber *maxValue = [results valueForKeyPath:@"@max.maxValue"]; (maxValue being the name of the NSExpressionDescription)
```

which worked!

I would like to know if I could stack the `sum:` and the `max:` into an `NSExpression`.